# c# Reading text files from class

Tags: c#, visual-studio, class

my code have 4 classes (id, books,teachers, courses) the purpose of my code is simple I ask the user for the path for the text file then read each line from the text file but I have to use class,  each class I've put a code for the path of the text file and a try, catch function to read it, my question is how do I or what function  should I use to read the lines from the classes in my (Program.cs)
for example here is my code from one of my classes

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
    namespace ConsoleApplication4
    {
        class books
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                String line;
                try
                {
                    //Pass the file path and file name to the StreamReader constructor
                    StreamReader books = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\R\Desktop\svu\programming_2\s21\books.txt");
                    //Read the first line of text
                    line = books.ReadLine();
                    //Continue to read until you reach end of file
                    while (line != null)
                    {
                        //write the line to console window
                        Console.WriteLine(line);
                        //Read the next line
                        line = books.ReadLine();
                    }
                    //close the file
                    books.Close();
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + e.Message);
                }
                finally
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Executing finally block.");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You mean something like this: [DotNetFiddle:ClassFromLines](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8Oq3Io)

Comment: It is not clear from your question exactly what you are trying to do & what your problem really is. Your example code does not show any classes & it is difficult to know what you are trying to do.

Comment: Half of the answer lies in the question itself. You sure *"id, books,teachers, courses"* is different `classes`, not `properties` or `fields` of ONE class? And what do you mean under "but I have to use class"? Use class to store readed from file data? Or use class to read data from file?

Comment: @PaulF my question is i have added multiple classes to my program.cs each class looks like the code In my question how can i use for example streamReader function fro, my books class in my original program.cs

Comment: @Auditive for example i have a stream reader function in my books class how can i use it in my program.cs

Comment: You need to create an instance of the books class & then call the method to read the file. If you have multiple classes that "look like the code in your question" - you should consider writing a base class that has the common code & deriving your other classes.

You should try again & then if you still have problems, try to write the question again with more detail of your problem & add the code for at least one of your classes, as it stands the question is very confusing & lacks some information we would need to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to read the lines from the classes in your Program.cs, you should create a function in the class such as ReadBooks instead of using the main function, such as the following code:

Code in books.cs:

```
class books
{
    public static void ReadBooks(string path) 
    {
        string line;
        try
        {
            //Pass the file path and file name to the StreamReader constructor
            StreamReader books = new StreamReader(path);
            //Read the first line of text
            line = books.ReadLine();
            //Continue to read until you reach end of file
            while (line != null)
            {
                //write the line to console window
                Console.WriteLine(line);
                //Read the next line
                line = books.ReadLine();
            }
            //close the file
            books.Close();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + e.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Executing finally block.");
        }
    }
}
```

Code in Program.cs:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string path;
        path = @"C:\Users\R\Desktop\svu\programming_2\s21\books.txt";
        books.ReadBooks(path);
    }
}
```